# Display "Select Resource" browser in VS designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a custom usercontrol that has an Image property.  The Image property is exposed to the designer.  After dragging an instance of my custom control onto a form and clicking on the Image property in the designer, the "Choose File" window comes up and lets me navigate to the file location to set the image as it should.

However, I would like it to open up the "Select Resource" window, so that I can choose to browse for an image or select a file from my projects Resources.  The "Select Resource" windows is what displays when you select the Image property on a Picturebox.

Select Resource Window:
[image]

How do I make my property display the "Select Resource" window instead of the "Choose File" window?

**Edit: I am using Visual Studio 2008**

Comment: Can't believe its been five years and still no answer LOL

Comment: Did you finally find any solution?